# pass ctrl+c to jupyter notebook launched remotely (ssh) by bash script

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook, remote-server, terminate

I have a bash script that launches a jupyter notebook remotely (ssh):

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -T user@remotehost << HERE
    # some code ...
    jupyter notebook --no-browser
HERE
```

I would like to terminate the notebook by pressing ctrl+c but have not found a way to pass the termination signal to the notebook while running it in the foreground (I would like to see the notebook output), so this does not work:

```
jupyer notebook --no-browser &
pid=$!
trap 'kill -2 ${pid}' SIGINT
```